# what does index.store.fs do

Tags: elasticsearch

I was under the impression that to use the mmapfs store, all I needed to do was set index.store.type to mmapfs, but I was reading this article and saw that the author did this

```
index: 
   store: 
     type: mmapfs 
     fs: 
       mmapfs: 
         enabled: true
```

so he basically did what I did then set
index.store.fs.mmapfs.enabled to true

My question is what does this the whole index.store.fs section do and where can I find some documentation on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only config you need is:

```
index.store.type: mmapfs
```

I don't know where the rest of that config was taken from - maybe it is from an older version.

The best place to see config settings to be sure of what is actually supported is in the code itself: 
https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/store/IndexStoreModule.java#L57

While on the subject of mmapfs, it is worth reading this blog entry:
http://blog.thetaphi.de/2012/07/use-lucenes-mmapdirectory-on-64bit.html